# How to display LaTeX code and the typeset version next to each other without repeating myself?

Tags: macros, listings, verbatim

I would like to write some LaTeX code, and without repeating myself, I would like that to be used for displaying that particular piece of code as-is and its typeset version, next to each other.

The solution in my head involves creating a command which shall take one required argument, which will be my LaTeX code; and this command shall use its argument to display it both inside some `verbatim`-like environment where it shall remain as-is, and outside where it shall be typeset.

However, something as in below does not work:

```
\newcommand{\codewithoutput}[1]
{
    \begin{verbatim}
        #1
    \end{verbatim}
    #1
}
```

And this is it, this is the best I can. I am completely stuck at here for the past 2 hours.

Since I am trying to display a LaTeX code here, using `\texttt[1]` or anything like that will not help, I think.

Comment: `tcolorbox` for example!

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/240317/how-can-i-typeset-an-environment-and-its-literal-equivalent-in-an-environment and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/128399/print-small-tex-code-verbatim-and-render-it

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The `tcolorbox` package can nicely display literal LaTeX code and its output when being called in a very configurable manner, depending on the argument of the `tcblisting` environment. This environment displays by default `LaTeX` code literally but the coding/scripting etc. language can be changed to anything known to the underlying `listings` package too (or `minted`, if needed)

Furthermore it allows documentation of LaTeX code with the `documentation` library (I use it for as documenation tool for my  personal packages too)

Please note that using complete documents to show `LaTeX` code is much more different (and difficult), of course.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}

\begin{tcblisting}{% Some options here
}
\newcommand{\codewithoutput}[1]
{
  This is a nice command and has the argument #1
}
\codewithoutput{\LaTeX}
\end{tcblisting}

% With some configuration of the tcblisting environment:     
\begin{tcblisting}{enhanced jigsaw,colback=yellow!40!white,drop lifted shadow}
\newcommand{\codewithoutput}[1]
{
  This is a nice command and has the argument #1
}
\codewithoutput{\LaTeX}
\end{tcblisting}


\end{document}
```

[image]