# Tikz externalisation fails to produce pdf output

Tags: tikz-external

Many pgfplots are included in my document, which are tikz-externalized, and run fine when the number of plots is less than 16. When I include the next pgfplot (even if it is a duplicate of the previously used ones) externalisation fails to produce the pdf (other files like md5, log are all created). While monitoring the output directory, it was noticed that the pdf file is first created, but then it gets deleted automatically. The log file of the particular plot reads like this:

```
......
Package pgfplots notification 'compat/show suggested version=true': document ha
s been generated with the most recent feature set (\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}).

(NP3.nav)
Runaway argument?
! File ended while scanning use of \headcommand.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.8 \begin{document}
                         
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 48453 strings out of 480797
 1126534 string characters out of 2905361
 1947551 words of memory out of 12000000
 63532 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
 537758 words of font info for 45 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 87i,7n,143p,1796b,790s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s

!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Note that, without externalisation everything is fine always. The tex memmory was increased to avoid capacity exceeding error. Does anybody know anything about this?

Comment: Can you tell us which engine you are using at is date?

Comment: @AndrewSwann, I am using pdflatex. Externalizing using pdflatex --shell-escape filename

Comment: Which version of pdflatex?

Comment: @AndrewSwann, My console shows this: MiKTeX-pdfTeX 2.9.7439 (1.40.21) (MiKTeX 2.9.7440 64-bit). I guess the pdflatex is 1.40.21.

Comment: Can you produce a minimal example demonstrating the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Are you by chance also using imakeidx along with tikzexternalize? I had the exact same issue, and it turns out I have to place imakeidx before tikzexternalize. i.e.

```
\makeindex
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize[prefix=tikz/]
```

See: [Source](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/393697/weird-behavior-with-glossaries-imakeidx-and-externalization-in-tikz)