# Typing code in-line

Tags: listings

I am using making a list of common math commands in LaTeX, and I'm using the `listings` package to put them in a code format. However, I want some of the commands to be in the same line, instead of having to take up a new line (sort of like we can type code inline vs in a block) but some to stay in a block. How can I do this? It doesn't have to use the `listings` package.

A sample of my code is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{listings,mdframed}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\diamondtimes}{%
  \mathbin{\text{\rotatebox[origin=c]{45}{$\boxplus$}}}%
}

\lstset{
  language=[LaTeX]TeX,
  backgroundcolor=\color{black!5}, % set backgroundcolor
  basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,% basic font setting
  columns=fullflexible,
}

\title{Math in LaTeX}
\author{v.0.1}

\begin{document}

\maketitle


\section{Simple, Inline Equations}

You can do a simple inline equation by using \begin{lstlisting}
$ an equation here $
\end{lstlisting}
For example, you might do 
\begin{lstlisting}
$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{2^n} i\bar z$
\end{lstlisting}which produces $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{2^n} i\bar z$.
\end{document}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Exanple from page 4 of the documentation: `\lstinline!var i:integer;!`

Comment: @samcarter, that works, but it doesn't highlight it in gray...

Comment: Tell it the language you want as optional argument.

Comment: For an alternative solution, you can have look on my answer to (a similar) question here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/279068/how-to-display-latex-code-and-the-typeset-version-next-to-each-other-without-rep/279069#279069

Comment: Is there any news here? If the comments helped, maybe we can ping one of the commentors to write an answer or even close as duplicate?

Comment: @Johannes_B, samcarter's answer was the most helpful; even though it doesn't outline it in gray, I can try to figure out the rest.

Comment: @samcarter Can you post an answer with grey font?

Comment: @Johannes_B I could, but I think she wants grey background rather  than font :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The grey background is actually a bit tricky, but luckily the `realboxes` package comes to help.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{realboxes}

\begin{document}
\Colorbox{gray}{\lstinline[language={[latex]TeX},basicstyle=\ttfamily]|$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{2^n} i\bar z$|}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: A bit hard to read, but the color can be adjusted. Thanks :-)

Comment: You're welcome! And thanks for the pinging me!

Comment: Perfect! +1. Thanks for your help!