# How can I print the color values of a color definition (without explicitly typing them again)?

Tags: tikz-pgf, color

I would like to define a group of colors and print the values of those colors without explicitly defining them again.

## `xcolor` Definitions

```
\definecolor{colora}{cmyk}{0,.5,1,.3}
\definecolor{colorb}{cmyk}{.4,.6,.5,.1}
\definecolor{colorc}{rgb}{1,0,0}
\definecolor{colord}{rgb}{0,0,1}
```

In reality I am using Percusse's fancy schmancy code from: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/235759/13552

I would like to create a color chart like that but
with the actual values (the hard part) AND the name of the color (the easy part) of the colors.

[image]

## Code

Code as it is from Percusse. I do not need rgb values, but they are in there for the sake of completeness.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}


\def\appendcolor#1#2#3{%
\csname pgfutil@ifundefined\endcsname{definedcolorsofar}{\def\definedcolorsofar{#1}}{%
\expandafter\def\expandafter\definedcolorsofar\expandafter{\definedcolorsofar,#1}}%
\definecolor{#1}{#2}{#3}%
}

\appendcolor{colora}{cmyk}{0,.5,1,.3}
\appendcolor{colorb}{cmyk}{.4,.6,.5,.1}
\appendcolor{colorc}{rgb}{1,0,0}
\appendcolor{colord}{rgb}{0,0,1}

\begin{document}
\tikz{
\foreach \x[count=\xi] in \definedcolorsofar 
   \node at (0,\xi)[fill=\x, minimum width=2cm, 
           minimum height=1cm,text=white] {\x}; 
}

\end{document}
```

## Bonus Code

Ideally, I could print the cmyk values + percentage of hiding power (opacity).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}%xelatex
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}


\def\appendcolor#1#2#3{%
\csname pgfutil@ifundefined\endcsname{definedcolorsofar}{\def\definedcolorsofar{#1}}{%
\expandafter\def\expandafter\definedcolorsofar\expandafter{\definedcolorsofar,#1}}%
\definecolor{#1}{#2}{#3}%
}

\appendcolor{colora}{cmyk}{0,.5,1,.3}
\appendcolor{colorb}{cmyk}{.4,.6,.5,.1}
\appendcolor{colorc}{rgb}{1,0,0}
\appendcolor{colord}{rgb}{0,0,1}

\newcommand\printcolors{
    \foreach \x[count=\xi] in \definedcolorsofar {
        \foreach \colorpercent[count=\coli] in {100,85,65,35,15} {
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro\step{\coli - 1}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\nodeselect{ifthenelse(equal(int(\step),0),"firstnode","restnode")}%
        \tikz [firstnode/.style={name=\x},restnode/.style={}] \node [\nodeselect,fill=\x!\colorpercent, minimum width=2cm, minimum height=1cm,text=white,outer sep=0pt, inner sep=0pt] {\colorpercent\%};%
        }%
    \hfill{\x}\par
    }%
}%

\begin{document}
\printcolors{}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think [Claudio's answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/66475/1952) to [how-to-get-actual-values-of-colour-theme-colours-in-beamer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66465/how-to-get-actual-values-of-colour-theme-colours-in-beamer) can help you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the values by first extracting any color definition's specs in RGB and converting into whatever color model

```
\extractcolorspecs{blue!20!red}{\model}{\mycolor}
\convertcolorspec{\model}{\mycolor}{cmyk}\tmp\tmp
```

will print out

```
0,0.8,0.6,0.2
```

and you can use those for whatever reason.