# How can I pass a macro to a macro and check for its existence?

Tags: macros

I hope this question makes sense. If I wanted to modify the following code to allow the user to pass a macro as the first parameter, how would I do it?

## How it is:

(using `pgf`)

```
\def\appendtolist#1{% <item>
  \csname pgfutil@ifundefined\endcsname{mylistmacro}{\def\mylistmacro{#1}}{% Instantiate list if not already
  \expandafter\def\expandafter\mylistmacro\expandafter{\mylistmacro^^J#1}}% Append to list
}%
```

## What I effectively want to do:

(using `pgf`)

```
\def\appendtolist#1#2{% <macro representing list> <item>
  \csname pgfutil@ifundefined\endcsname{#1}{\def\ithapplist{#1}}{% Instantiate list if not already
  \expandafter\def\expandafter#1\expandafter{\ithapplist^^J#1}}% Append to list
}%
```

## Problem

After `\endcsname` I need to supply a macro name without the backslash.

Even if I use this other syntax for determining whether or not the macro has been defined, I still run into this problem.

### Other csname checks

#### TeX Kernel

https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/30484/13552

```
\ifcsname#1\endcsname%
    ... command '#1' exists ...%
  \else%
    ... command '#1' does not exist ...%
  \fi%
```

#### LateX kernel

https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/30486/13552*emphasized text*

```
\@ifundefined{foo}
  {%
    % \foo not defined
  }
  {%
    % \foo defined
  }%
```

## Ultimate Goal

Normally I spit out things to the log during runtime using `\typeout`. Instead, I'd like to append them to a macro (delimited variable) that I can call later with something like `\typeout\expandafter{\aggregatedlogentries}`. This would keep certain things grouped in the log.

## Example

*Does not compile*

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{pgf}
 \def\appendtolist#1{% <item>
       \csname pgfutil@ifundefined\endcsname{mylistmacro}{\def\mylistmacro{#1}}{% Instantiate list if not already
       \expandafter\def\expandafter\mylistmacro\expandafter{\mylistmacro^^J#1}}% Append to list
     }%
\begin{document}
\newcount\step
\step = 0%
\loop
  \appendtolist{\step}% <== I want to be able to provide a macro name as arg1 and item as arg2!
  \advance\step by 1%
  \unless\ifnum \step>10 %space important
\repeat %

\typeout{\mylistmacro}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think it's best to define `\mylistmacro` to be empty and then define  new `\appendtolist` using internal command `\g@addto@macro`

Comment: @touhami That sounds promising

Comment: why are you using `\csname pgfutil@ifundefined\endcsname` rather than `\pgfutil@ifundefined` ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Because I am copying Percusse's code :D http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/235759/13552 (which I assumed could not be such a bad approach) I got the part about `\unless` and e-TeX from egreg at  http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/62381/13552

Comment: `\unless` is a primitive, the `etex` package does not define it (and should not be loaded into current latex as it will undo all the new allocation code)

Comment: No. @egreg does not mention the `etex` package there.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Care to elaborate? Does "e-TeX's `\unless`" mean something different than `etex`'s `\unless`?

Comment: yes e-tex is an extended tex engine that is used for almost all formats except (dvi) plain tex in modern distributions (the etex extensions are included in pdftex, luatex and xetex as well as etex itself)  that defines some additional primitives like \unless, \numexpr, etc and increases the number of count registers from 256 to 2^15 etex.sty is latex package which used to be used to change \newcount to use the extended range, but isn't needed now at all.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks. Code has been adjusted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is clear example when programmer solves a problem which does not exsist by complicated macro packages (like `pgf`). You can simply do:

```
\def\appendtolist#1#2{%
   \ifx#1\undefined \def#1{#2}\else   
   \expandafter\def\expandafter#1\expandafter{#1^^J#2}\fi % Append to list
}%

\appendtolist\ithaplist{aha} \appendtolist\ithaplist{uha}
```

Comment: @wipet May I suggest being a little less judgmental here. I had no idea what approach to take. I decided to start with Percusse's approach, simply because I think he is a skilled coder. Whether it is wise or not is another question :)

Comment: @macmadness86 I don't know what does mean "judgmental" but I strongly recommend first to learn TeX istself and second a features of some packages.

Comment: @wipet I mean that perhaps there is a reason Percusse used `pgf` of which you or I am unaware of. As for why I used it here, I might have some things behind the scenes going on that are not in the question (I don't in this case, but is often the case on stackexchange). Perhaps that is one of the downsides of  minimal examples.

Comment: @macmadness86 percusse was answering a question that the OP had tagged as tikz-pgf and was using tikz for the actual drawing. In such a case, using the supplied loop macro in pgf makes sense, but if you _just_ want a loop macro loading half a million lines of tikz code to get it might be considered excessive.

Answer (score 2):

Your code did not produce an error but simply defined `\mylistmacro` to be 10 `\step` as you appended  literally the tokens `\step^^J` 10 times, here I append the expansion of `\step`'s current value, although as wipet rightly notes this is using several orders of magnitude more code than required for the stated use case.

```
 \documentclass{article}
%no \usepackage{etex}% for \unless
 \usepackage{pgf}
\makeatletter
 \def\appendtolist#1{% <item>
       \pgfutil@ifundefined{mylistmacro}{\def\mylistmacro{#1}}{% Instantiate list if not already
       \expandafter\def\expandafter\mylistmacro\expandafter{\mylistmacro^^J#1}}% Append to list
     }%
\begin{document}
\newcount\step
\step = 0%
\loop
  \expandafter\appendtolist\expandafter{\the\step}% <== I want to be able to provide a macro name as arg1 and item as arg2!
  \advance\step by 1%
  \unless\ifnum \step>10 %space important
\repeat %



\typeout{\mylistmacro}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The LaTeX3 programming layer `expl3` provides a lot of macros for these kinds of things.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \l_macmad_mylist_seq

\int_step_inline:nnnn { 0 } { 1 } { 10 }
 { \seq_put_right:Nn \l_macmad_mylist_seq { #1 } }

\seq_use:Nn \l_macmad_mylist_seq { ,~ }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

With `etoolbox`:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand{\appendtolist}[2]{%
  \ifundef{#1}{\gdef#1{== \string#1 ==}}{}%
  \gappto#1{^^J#2}%
}

\appendtolist\mylistmacro{abc}
\appendtolist\mylistmacro{def}
\appendtolist\mylistmacro{ghi}
\appendtolist\mylistmacro{lmn}

\typeout{\mylistmacro}
```

Output on terminal:

```
== \mylistmacro ==
abc
def
ghi
lmn
```

More customizable, because you can define whatever usage you want for the made list, just varying how `\showlist` is defined.

```
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\appendtolist}{mm}
 {
  \seq_if_exist:cF { g_macmadness_typeout_#1_seq }
   { \seq_new:c { g_macmadness_typeout_#1_seq } }
  \seq_gput_right:cn { g_macmadness_typeout_#1_seq } { #2 }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\showlist}{m}
 {
  \typeout
   {
    ==~#1~==^^J
    \seq_use:cn { g_macmadness_typeout_#1_seq } { ^^J }
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\appendtolist{mylistmacro}{abc}
\appendtolist{mylistmacro}{def}
\appendtolist{mylistmacro}{ghi}
\appendtolist{mylistmacro}{lmn}

\showlist{mylistmacro}
```

Output on terminal

```
== mylistmacro ==
abc
def
ghi
lmn
```